# How to proove that a norm N verifies $ N(x) \leq k||x|| $

Tags: normed-spaces

This seems very obvious but I don't know how to prove it (bearing in mind I cannot use the equivalence of norms as it is the ultimate goal of the exercise to prove it):

I have a norm N:
$ N: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow [0;+\infty[ $

I am trying to prove that: $ \exists k>0, \forall x, N(x)\leq k \Vert x \Vert $
where $ \Vert. \Vert $ is another unspecified norm.
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: A norm is always $\geq0$ so you can divide by $||x||$ to get $\frac{N(x)}{||x||}\leq k$, so you can just take $k=[\frac{N(x)}{||x||}]+1$(I assumed $k\in\mathbb{N}$), $[]$ being the floor function.

Comment: But it is $ \forall x $, so $ \frac{N(x)}{\Vert x \Vert} $ can tend towards infinite.

Comment: That could only happen if $||x||=0$. This implies $x=0$ and $N(x)=0$ so in this case any $k$ will do.

Comment: The magic word is compactness.

Comment: That could only happen if ||||=0. This implies =0 and ()=0 so in this case any  will do.> The case of 0 is clear, but N(x) could tend towards infinite with $\Vert x \Vert$ much smaller?

Comment: The magic word is compactness.> :D. Compactness of which subset? $ \frac{N(x)}{\Vert x\Vert } $?

Comment: Still wondering why I got a downvote while nobody was able to find the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out:

- first I wrote N in a canonical basis,
- then I used Cauchy Schwarz inequality